# Getting icon from exe in .net compact framework

Tags: .net, icons, compact-framework, exe

I am developing some windows forms application for Windows Embedded Compact 7 that imitates desktop shell using .net compact framework and c# Smart Device project type. I use `SHGetFileInfo` WinAPI function to get associated icon from exe file, here is my code below:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct SHFILEINFO
{
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public IntPtr iIcon;
    public uint dwAttributes; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string szDisplayName;      
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szTypeName; 

    public SHFILEINFO(bool setDefaults)
    {
        hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
        iIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
        dwAttributes = 0;
        szDisplayName = "";
        szTypeName = "";
    }
}
public class Win32
{
    public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x000000100; 
    public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x00000000; 
    public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x00000001; 

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath,
                                              int dwFileAttributes,
                                              ref SHFILEINFO psfi,
                                              uint cbSizeFileInfo,
                                              uint uFlags);
 }
```

and then I call this function from here:

```
private static Icon ExtractIconFromExe(string targetPath)
{
IntPtr hImgLarge; 
var shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
hImgLarge = Win32.SHGetFileInfo(targetPath,
                                0,
                                ref shinfo,
                                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),
                                Win32.SHGFI_ICON);
var icon = Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);
return icon;
}
```

It's works fine on my Windows 7 Ultimate (using shell32.dll instead coredll.dll of course), but when I try to run this code on Windows Embedded or Smart Device emulator I have uninformative exception in this line: `Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon)`. Does anybody know how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What file is `targetPath`? Does it exist on Windows Embedded? Is it Empty or Null? We don't know!

Put some error checking code in there.

Your `IntPtr hImgLarg` is set specifically so you can verify the return value is not an error number before you proceed.

Also, when writing your checks, look at `shinfo` - and specifically see if `SHGetFileInfo` populates `shinfo.hIcon`.

You could be passing a `NULL` to `Icon.FromHandle`.